# Как скопировать файлы в одном цикле?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

```
public static void CopyPackFiles()
{
    var SB = new StringBuilder();
    bool Exists = Directory.Exists(@"C:\GamePack");
        try
        {
            if (!Exists)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(str2 + folder);
                foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(GetPath()).GetFiles("*.d3d", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(str2, file.Name));
                }
                foreach (var file2 in new DirectoryInfo(GetPath() + folder).GetFiles("*.ini", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    file2.CopyTo(Path.Combine(str2 + folder, file2.Name));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) { SB.AppendLine(e.ToString()); }
        catch (SecurityException e) { SB.AppendLine(e.ToString()); }
        catch (Exception e) { SB.AppendLine(e.ToString()); }
        File.WriteAllText("Error.log", SB.ToString());
}
```

Как сделать копирование файлов в 1 часть папки, а 2 часть во внутреннею папку с использование Linq ?

Можно ли обойтись без вторичного цикла ( где копируется во внутреннею папку файлы)?!

Нужно ли использовать в этом примере Task ?

Comment: Пути стоит складывать через `Path.Combine`. Вместо `new DirectoryInfo(GetPath() + folder).GetFiles` можно использовать `Directory.GetFiles`. LINQ тут особо не нужен, максимум - можно склеить результат вызовов двух `GetFiles` через `Concat`, и прогнать один цикл по результату :)

Comment: @PashaPash, Можете дать пример как ответ)

Comment: @PashaPash, Я кстати вроде как бы и использовал `Path.Combine` внутри цикла) Мне интересно как сложить в 1 цикле с `Concat` сложить, будьте любезны привести пример кода, я просто не видел как делают это при копирование или тому подобному.

Comment: вы вы использовали Path.Combine, но не во всех местах. `str2 + folder`. Я бы запостил пример, но с LINQ он получается страшный и менее читабельный. LINQ используется для построения запросов. А вам тут запрос не нужен, два цикла (или метод) проще и читабельнее. Не нужен тут ни LINQ ни Task.

Comment: Ясно, то есть просто за место `+` ставим Path.Combine :) Спасибо, но вот с Concat интересно увидеть всё-таки в одном цикле

Comment: там будет некрасивый нечитабельный код. я не хочу его писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string targetBaseFolder = str2;
string targetSubFolder = Path.Combine(targetBaseFolder, folder); // один раз, а не в цикле
Directory.CreateDirectory(targetSubFolder);

string sourceFolder = GetPath();
string sourceSubfolder = Path.Combine(sourceFolder, folder); 

CopyFiles(sourceFolder, targetBaseFolder, "*.d3d"); 
CopyFiles(sourceSubfolder, targetSubFolder, "*.ini");

private static void CopyFiles(string from, string to, string searchPattern)
{
    // SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly - значение по умолчанию
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(from, searchPattern)) 
    { 
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(to, Path.GetFileName(file)));
    }
}
```

LINQ не нужен. Task - в зависимости от того, кто вызывает этот код, и ожидает ли он асинхроности